# Simulation data fitting

Tags: curve-fitting, curve

I have 154 scatter points and I want to fit them.
What is the best way to fit them to a curve? I tried with Excel sheet to fit the data to polynomial curve  but I found the highest fitting power is 6. which program or numerical technique would help in fitting these data?

Comment: Please post a link to the text data.

Comment: Is it x-y-data? Did you check python and the python module scipy.optimize? GNUPlot also allows to fit data. I am not a friend of Excel, but you can enhance its capabilities with Virtual Basic. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964202/vba-excel-fitting-curve-with-freely-choosen-function)